# How long until MySQL transaction times out

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, e-commerce

How long can a MySQL transaction last until it times out? I'm asking because I'm planning to code an payment process for my e-commerce project somewhere along the lines of this (PHP/MySQL psuedo-code):

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT...WHERE id IN (1,2,3) AND available = 1 FOR UPDATE; //lock rows where "available" is true

//Do payment processing...

//add to database, commit or rollback based on payment results
```

I can not think of another way to lock the products being bought (so if two users buy it at the same time, and there is only one left in stock, one user won't be able to buy), process payment if products are available, and create a record based on payment results...

Answer (score 1):

That technique would also block users who simply wanted to **see** the products other people are buying. I'd be exceptionally wary of any technique that relies on database row locking to enforce inventory management.

Instead, why not simply record the number of items currently tied up in an active "transaction" (here meaning the broader commercial sense, rather than the technical database sense). If you have a `current_inventory` field, add an `on_hold` or `being_paid_for` or `not_really_available_because_they_are_being_used_elsewhere` field that you can update with information on current payments.

Better yet, why not use a purchase / payment log to sum the items currently "on hold" or "in processing" for several different users.

This is the general approach you often see on sites like Ticketmaster that declare, "You have X minutes to finish this page, or we'll put these tickets back on the market." They're recording which items the user is currently trying to buy, and those records can even persist across PHP page requests.

Comment: Select FOR UPDATE does not block concurrent reads in innodb (that is, normal select queries). Select for update only blocks locking queries (other update queries and delete queries). It will also block special selects like other select FOR UPDATES and select LOCK IN SHARE MODE

Answer (score 0):

Timeout depends on server settings -- both that of mysql and that of the language you are using to interact with mysql.  Look in the settings files for your server.

I don't think what you are doing would cause a timeout, but if you are worried you might want to rethink the location of your check so that it doesn't actually lock the tables across queries.  You could instead have a stored procedure that is built into the data layer rather than relying on two separate calls.  Or, maybe a conditional insert or a conditional update?

All in all, as another person noted, I don't like the idea of locking entire table rows which you might want to be able to select from for other purposes outside of the actual "purchase" step, as it could result in problems or bottlenecks elsewhere in your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to ask how long it is before a database connection times out, then your transactions take orders of magnitudes too long.

Long open transactions are a big problem and frequent causes of poor performance, unrepeatable bugs or even deadlocking the complete application. Certainly in a web application you want tight fast transactions to make sure all table and row level locks are quickly freed.

I found that even several 100ms can become troublesome.

Then there is the problem of sharing a transaction over multiple requests which may happen concurrently.

If you need to "emulate" long running transactions, cut it into smaller pieces which can be executed fast, and keep a log so you can rollback using the log by undoing the transactions.

Now, if the payment service completes in 98% of cases in less than 2 sec and you do not have hundreds of concurrent requests going on, it might just be fine.